# Mongoose Index on a field in nested document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a small schema

```
var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  link: String,
  author: {type:String,required:true},
  upvotes: {type: Number, default: 0},
  nesteddoc : {
      field1: String
  }
});

//This is broken - index on field1
PostSchema.index({nesteddoc.field1:1},{unique:true});
```

Is it possible to have an index on nested field by specifying in Mongoose schema and not running a MongoDB query to ensure the index ?

Answer (score 21):

Use quotes around `"nesteddoc.field1"` to evaluate the nested field :

```
PostSchema.index({ "nesteddoc.field1": 1 }, { unique: true });
```

Furthermore, mongoose will call `ensureIndex` internally, from [mongoose doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes) :

> When your application starts up, Mongoose automatically calls
>   ensureIndex for each defined index in your schema. Mongoose will call
>   ensureIndex for each index sequentially, and emit an 'index' event on
>   the model when all the ensureIndex calls succeeded or when there was
>   an error. While nice for development, it is recommended this behavior
>   be disabled in production since index creation can cause a significant
>   performance impact. Disable the behavior by setting the autoIndex
>   option of your schema to false, or globally on the connection by
>   setting the option config.autoIndex to false.

You can also define index in schema :

```
var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    link: String,
    author: { type: String, required: true },
    upvotes: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    nesteddoc: {
        field1: { type: String, unique: true, index: true },
    }
});
```

Comment: How can I make same embedded field to be indexed for full text search?

Comment: PostSchema.index({ "nesteddoc.field1": "text" });

Comment: Could someone provide a link to mongoose documentation page where this is stated ?

Comment: What is that 1 in the index? why no one explains that?

Comment: @shinzou 1 is ascending index, -1 is descending index, see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/#db.collection.createIndex

Comment: Hi there the code doesn't work for me when I do `Schema.index({"location.city": "text"})` can someone help me? Because it doesn't when I do a text search.