# Ensure a unique index on nested reference on a mongoose schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, indexing

What I want is that a user can like a post only once, hence I uniquely indexed the `user` in the `likes` array to ensure the same, but it isn't working and I can't find out what is wrong here .

The schema looks like this :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  author: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User' // User model
  },
  text: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Post must have some text']
  },
  likes: [
    {
      user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
      }
    }
  ],
  comments: [
    {
      author: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
      },
      text: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Comment must have some text']
      },
      addedAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
      }
    }
  ],
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
})

postSchema.pre(/^find/, function(next) {
  this.populate({
    path: 'author',
    select: 'name avatar'
  }).populate({
    path: 'comments.author',
    select: 'name avatar'
  })

  next()
})

// Ensure a user can like a post only once
postSchema.index({ 'likes.user': 1 }, { unique: true })

const Post = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema)

module.exports = Post
```

However when I send a post request to like a post twice via the same user it 
shows no error.
Here is the postman output [image: Same user in the likes array twice, this shouldn't happen .]

I have tried both the ways listed in this, but none of them worked in this case.
[Mongoose Index on a field in nested document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42368354/mongoose-index-on-a-field-in-nested-document)

How do I ensure a user can like a post only once from the schema itself ?

Answer (score -1):

Try saving likes in this format in the database

likes:[{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'User'}]

making it

likes:[ObjectId("5af03111967c60501d97781f")]

and when the post like API is hit do

{$addToSet: {likedBy: userId}}

in update query,addToSet ensures no duplicate ids are maintained in the array.